# How did the meaning of the word “play” spread from games to things that are not games?

Tags: meaning, etymology

You can play a role in a film (movie), you can play a musical instrument in an orchestra. However, these activities are more work than a game. In ancient Roman theaters, slaves played, and it is difficult to say that it was entertainment for them. It was rather their job.

According to [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=play):

> Meaning “to take part in” a martial or athletic game is from c. 1200.
> It has been opposed to work (v.) since late 14c.

Did the word “play” begin to refer to activities that were not considered work?

What is the etymology of the word “play” in meanings unrelated to games? For example: to play in the theater or in a film (movie), to play a musical instrument.

Comment: The second sentence that you quote answers your own question.

Comment: This is very ancient. Play is what children do. Games are one example; another is drama (what we still call "play-acting"), still another singing and shouting. All children everywhere do these and always have. And they don't differentiate much between competitive and cooperative play, or loud noise and music, and switch back and forth. Just like real life. But if you're only playing, you don't die when you lose, and the villain in the play doesn't die, and the song ends, and you go home.

Comment: You're not citing: The nail was too loose; there was a lot of play in it.

Comment: And at some point it develops the meaning of manipulate: We were played.

Comment: @Xanne An interesting example. Perhaps this is due to the understanding of a game as something that is not a reality. The facts that were given to someone were a deliberately created illusion. Therefore, the person made the wrong decision.

Comment: @Kate Bunting How, then, can we define play and work? Could work mean something that creates material wealth: food, clothing, housing, etc. And game, on the other hand, does not create products that a person needs for life. Game is a way of interestingly occupying yourself in your free time. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: _Play_ has developed a number of meanings over the centuries, _one_ of which is 'activities that aren't work' - things you do for fun and not practical necessity.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you for your help. I had such a guess after reading “It has been opposed to work”, but I was not sure if I was right. I am grateful that you gave me confirmation. Today, people like actors and musicians can make a lot of money from their activities, but their activities are not necessary, as are competitive games. It may seem that there is nothing in common between playing the violin and playing football, but in fact there is.

Comment: I said that that was _one_ meaning. Acting a part and performing on a musical instrument are _other_ meanings of 'play'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I’m confused. My question was: *“How did the meaning of the word ‘play’ spread from games to things that are not games?”* Your first comment was: *“The second sentence that you quote answers your own question”.* And  I asked for clarification: *“How, then, can we define play and work?”* You answered: *“Play has developed a number of meanings over the centuries, one of which is activities that aren’t work - things you do for fun and not practical necessity”.* You have said today: *“Acting a part and performing on a musical instrument are other meanings of ‘play’.”*

Comment: @Kate Bunting And where did we come to?

Comment: It answers the question _Did the word “play” begin to refer to activities that were not considered work?_ (Yes, in the 14th century.) _Other_ meanings are 'to act a part' and 'to make music'. I don't think we can know exactly when each sense of the word evolved.

Comment: @Lambie a lot of play in what, the *plywood*?

Comment: note that *work* covers part of the same semantic space as play, e.g. a *work* in theatre is a *play*, you have to work an instrument to play music (*plicare*, might be it if talking about plugged string instruments), and as JLawler said it, children don't strictly distinguish their exercise from work or play.

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence of the etymonline entry has:

> Middle English pleien, from Old English plegan, plegian "move lightly and quickly, occupy or busy oneself, amuse oneself; engage in active exercise; frolic; engage in children's play; make sport of, mock; perform music," from Proto-West Germanic *plegōjanan "occupy oneself about"

So it has had the senses of performing music and children's frolicking for as long as it's been a part of the English language. It's the senses related to sport and to the stage that developed later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your quote at the end: “from Proto-West Germanic *plegōjanan “occupy oneself about”. Perhaps it was originally meant to occupy yourself with something that is not work? And work could mean something that creates material wealth: food, clothing, housing, etc. Game, on the other hand, does not create products that a person needs for life. Game is a way of interestingly occupying yourself in your free time. Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

1 who knows how to'play'àn instrument is someone who can make the instrument work

Yet we say play the piano, play a song & work a piano yes but work a song's wrong

But still, work a song actually means to use that song to your ultimate advantage

Maybe play means deliberately influence?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).